# How to correctly use Nginx as reverse proxy for multiple Apache Docker containers with SSL?

Tags: apache, docker, ssl, nginx, proxy

**Given the following docker containers:**

- an `nginx` service that runs an unmodified official [`nginx:latest`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/nginx/library/nginx/latest/images/sha256-6d73b8284d351c649a33827d46c9835d73aca9f8df4903607319880e0d4b7194?context=explore) image

  - container name: **`proxy`**
- two applications running in separate containers based on modified official [`php:7.4.1-apache`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.4.1-apache/images/sha256-13f38be205271e9744e4dd0bd5d0b384e9fad94d8a367d076e33dbf1635c57da?context=explore) images

  - container names: **`app1`** and **`app2`**
- all containers `proxy`, `app1`, and `app2` are in the same Docker-created network with automatic DNS resolution

**With the following example domain names:**

- `local.web.test`
- `local1.web.test`
- `local2.web.test`

**I want to achieve the following behavior:**

- serve `local.web.test` from `nginx` as the default server block
- configure `nginx` to proxy requests from `local1.web.test` and `local2.web.test` to `app1` and `app2`, respectively, both listening on port `80`
- configure `nginx` to serve all three domain names using a [wildcard SSL certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)

**I experience two problems:**

1. I notice the following error in the `nginx` logs:

   - `2020/06/28 20:00:59 [crit] 27#27: *36 SSL_read() failed (SSL: error:14191044:SSL routines:tls1_enc:internal error) while waiting for request, client: 172.19.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443`
2. the `mod_rpaf` seems not to work properly (i.e., the `ip` address in the `apache` access logs is of the `nginx` server [e.g., `172.19.0.2`] instead of the `ip` of the client that issues the request

   - `172.19.0.2 - - [28/Jun/2020:20:05:05 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 404 457 "http://local1.web.test/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NTndows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36`
   - the output of `phpinfo()` for **Apache Environment** shows that:

     - `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` lists the client `ip`
     - `SERVER_ADDR` lists the `app1` container `ip` (e.g., `172.19.0.4`)
     - `REMOTE_ADDR` shows the `proxy` container `ip` (e.g., `172.19.0.2`) instead of the client `ip`

---

To make this reproducible, this is how everything is set up. I tried this on my Windows machine so there are two preliminary steps.

1. **Preliminary steps**

   a. in my `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file I added the following:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 local.web.test
   127.0.0.1 local1.web.test
   127.0.0.1 local2.web.test
   ```

   b. I generated a self-signed SSL certificate with the **Common Name** set to **`*.local.test`** via

   ```bash
   openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt
   ```
2. **The `proxy` service setup**

   a. the `nginx.yml` for the `docker-compose`:

   ```yaml
   version: "3.8"

   services:
       nginx:
           image: nginx:latest
           container_name: proxy
           ports:
               - "80:80"
               - "443:443"
           volumes:
               - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
               - ./certs:/etc/ssl/nginx
               - ./static/local.web.test:/usr/share/nginx/html
           networks:
               - proxy
   networks:
       proxy:
           driver: bridge
   ```

   b. within `./nginx` that is bind mounted at `/etc/nginx/conf.d` there is a file `default.conf` that contains:

   ```
   server {
       listen 80 default_server;
       server_name local.web.test;

       location / {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
       }
   }

   server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name local.web.test;

       location / {
           root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
           index  index.html index.htm;
       }

       ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/localhost.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/localhost.key;
   }
   ```

   c. the `./certs:/etc/ssl/nginx` bind mounts the folder containing the self-signed certificate and key

   d. the `./static/local.web.test:/usr/share/nginx/html` makes available a file `index.html` that contains

   ```html
   <h1>local.web.test</h1>
   ```
3. **The `app1` and `app2` services setup**

   a. the `apache.yml` for the `docker-compose`:

   ```yaml
   version: "3.8"

   services:
       app1:
           build:
               context: .
               dockerfile: apache.dockerfile
           image: app1
           container_name: app1
           volumes:
               - ./static/local1.web.test:/var/www/html
           networks:
               - exp_proxy

       app2:
           build:
               context: .
               dockerfile: apache.dockerfile
           image: app2
           container_name: app2
           volumes:
               - ./static/local2.web.test:/var/www/html
           networks:
               - exp_proxy

   networks:
       # Note: the network is named `exp_proxy` because the root directory is `exp`.
       exp_proxy:
           external: true
   ```

   b. the `apache.dockerfile` image looks like this:

   ```bash
   # Base image.
   FROM php:7.4.1-apache

   # Install dependencies.
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl nano wget unzip build-essential apache2-dev

   # Clear cache.
   RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

   # Change working directory,
   WORKDIR /root

   # Fetch mod_rpaf.
   RUN wget https://github.com/gnif/mod_rpaf/archive/stable.zip

   # Unzip.
   RUN unzip stable.zip

   # Change working directory,
   WORKDIR /root/mod_rpaf-stable

   # Compile and install.
   RUN make && make install

   # Register the module for load.
   RUN echo "LoadModule rpaf_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rpaf.so" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.load

   # Copy the configuration for mod_rpaf.
   COPY ./apache/mods/rpaf.conf /etc/apache2/mods-available/rpaf.conf

   # Enable the module.
   RUN a2enmod rpaf

   # Set working directory.
   WORKDIR /var/www/html
   ```

   c. the file `./apache/mods/rpaf.conf` copied contains:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
       RPAF_Enable             On
       RPAF_Header             X-Real-Ip
       RPAF_ProxyIPs           127.0.0.1
       RPAF_SetHostName        On
       RPAF_SetHTTPS           On
       RPAF_SetPort            On
   </IfModule>
   ```

   d. the `./static/local1.web.test:/var/www/html` bind mounts an `index.php` file containing:

   ```php
   <h1>local1.web.test</h1>
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   ```

   *the same goes for `./static/local2.web.test:/var/www/html`*

   e. the `000-default.conf` virtual hosts in `app1` and `app2` are not modified:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. **Starting the setup**

   a. start the `proxy` server

   ```
   docker-compose -f nginx.yml up -d --build
   ```

   b. start the `app1` and `app2` services

   ```
   docker-compose -f apache.yml up -d --build
   ```

   c. check containers to see if `mod_rpaf` is enabled

   ```
   docker-compose -f apache.yml exec app1 apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES
   ```

   d. add two files in `./nginx` that will be available on the `proxy` container at `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

   - `local1.web.test.conf` containing

   ```
   upstream app-1 {
       server app1;
   }

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name local1.web.test;

       location / {
           return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
       }
   }

   server {
       listen 443 ssl;
       server_name local1.web.test;

       location / {
           proxy_pass http://app-1;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       }

       ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx/localhost.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx/localhost.key;
   }
   ```

   - the second file is `local2.web.test.conf` with a similar setup (i.e., number `1` is replaced with `2`)

   e. check the config and restart the `proxy` container (or reload the `nginx` server)

   ```
   docker-compose -f nginx.yml exec proxy nginx -t 
   docker-compose -f nginx.yml exec proxy service nginx reload
   ```

**The issues:**

1. when I run `docker logs proxy -f` I notice the SSL internal error mentioned above: `SSL_read() failed`

   - someone faced a similar error ([http2: SSL read failed while sending req in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42170452/5252007)) but in that case, the message more specifically points to the certificate authority
2. if I run `docker logs app1 -f` and visit `https://local1.web.test`, the `ip` in the `GET` request matches the `ip` of the `proxy` container (i.e., `172.19.0.2`) and not that of the remote client

   - I suspect the cuprit is this `RPAF_ProxyIPs 127.0.0.1`, but I can't manually fix the `ip` because I don't know what `ip` the container will get in the `exp_proxy` network
   - also I can't use the hostname because `RPAF_ProxyIPs` expects an `ip`
   - `docker inspect proxy` shows `"IPAddress": "172.19.0.2"`
   - `docker inspect app1` shows `"IPAddress": "172.19.0.4"`

I can't seem to understand what goes wrong and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this quite reliably, with this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.0"
networks:
  network-1:
    name: network-1
    driver: bridge
  network-2:
    name: network-2
    driver: bridge

services:

  rprxy:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: ngxprxy
    networks:
      - network-1
      - network-2
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 8443:8443
    restart: unless-stopped

  web-1:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: web1
    networks:
      - network-1
    depends_on:
      - rprxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
      
  web-2:
    image: httpd:latest
    container_name: web2
    networks:
      - network-2
    depends_on:
      - rprxy
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs:ro
```

Then I run:

```
docker compose up -d
```

This creates and launches (2) internal networks, and (2) Web containers (one httpd, one nginx), one on each internal network; plus a bare nginx container on both internal networks.  The volume mounts point to /var/www/html on the host, where the Web content resides.  At this point, the reverse proxy is not configured, except that it has TCP ports 443 and 8443 exposed.  Use `docker ps` to show the running containers.

For a testbed, self-signed certificates can be created on the host with:

```
  openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.crt
```

Otherwise, a genuine set of certs can be used, if available.

To configure the reverse proxy, I create the nginx.conf file with:

```
worker_processes 1;
events { worker_connections 1024; }
 
http {
  sendfile on;

  upstream docker-web-1 {
    server web-1:80;
  }
  upstream docker-web-2 {
    server web-2:80;
  }

  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/selfsigned.key;
    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://docker-web-1;
      proxy_redirect     off;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/selfsigned.key;
    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://docker-web-2;
      proxy_redirect     off;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this configuration is using the self-signed certs.  The two Web containers are each internally using (unsecure) TCP port 80, which is being translated to secure ports 443 and 8443 by the reverse proxy.

Then I copy the (self-signed) certs and nginx.conf file to the reverse proxy container with:

```
docker cp nginx.conf ngxprxy:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
docker cp selfsigned.crt ngxprxy:/etc/nginx/
docker cp selfsigned.key ngxprxy:/etc/nginx/
docker restart ngxprxy
```

If all is done right, the reverse proxy container (ngxprxy) restarts with the new configuration, and I can test access with a Web browser to the proxied Web sites:

```
https://<host IP or FQDN>
https://<host IP or FQDN>:8443
```

It works!

Or, I can test from the host's CLI:

```
curl https://localhost
curl https://localhost:8443
```

If I discover that I have goofed up any configuration, I can stop and remove the containers with `docker stop` and `docker rm` commands.  Then I can fix either the docker-compose.yml or the nginx.conf file, and simply re-run the `docker compose up -d` command to generate a new set of containers.

In actual practice, I created 7 containers (1 Web site, 1 application, 1 database on each internal network, plus the proxy); but this was the starting point to prove the concept.